# Function confusion in return value, what is true and false explicitly?

Tags: c, if-statement, return, return-value

I am new to C, and in StackExchange here and all other sources, `0` is success, else is `false`. In this function to print prime numbers, why does it only print prime numbers if `return` value is 1?

like if I go `(is_prime(num) == 0)`, then it will not print prime number, but if just said `is_prime(num)` it automatically assumes `(is_prime(num) == 1)` ?

This has confused me, please clarify because the value will switch between 0 and 1, but why the bias automatically?

```
int is_prime(int num){
   int isPrime = 1;
   int i;

   for(i = 2; i <= sqrt(num); i++){
      if(num % i == 0){
         isPrime =  0;
      }
   }

   return isPrime;
}
```

Comment: success is not the opposite of false when the question is "What error occurred?"

Comment: My question is, why dies it bias to (is_prime(num) == 1) automatically, it should print everything because I haven't stated if it must equal 1 or 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am new to C, and in StackExchange here and all other sources, 0 is success, else is false.

That's backwards. In C, 0 is false and non-zero values are true.

```
if (number)    <==>   if (number != 0)
if (!number)   <==>   if (number == 0)
```

This is true most of the time and is the most common integer → boolean relationship. There are a few exceptions where the mapping is reversed:

- The return value of `main()` is 0 for success, non-zero for failure. The reason for this is if a program fails you may want to distinguish between errors by returning different exit codes. For instance, 1 for "bad command line arguments", 2 for "file not found", 3 for "could not connect to server", etc. The meaning of these exit codes is application-dependent.
- Many POSIX system calls such as `close()` and `connect()` use the same idea, returning 0 for success and -1 for errors. For these functions you must write `if (connect(...) != 0)` rather than `if (connect(...))`.

Note that these exceptions are not part of the C language itself, but rather with commonly-used C functions.

Answer (score 1):

In an if statement, or any case where a boolean value (True or false) is being tested, in C, at least, `0` represents false, and any nonzero integer represents true.

If, for some reason, your isPrime function returned `-17` given some input `x`, `isPrime(x)` would still be considered true if taken as a boolean, and thus if you had some code inside an if block whose condition was `isPrime(x)`, that code would be run, because `-17` is nonzero.